# Creating a gradient border of uiview with fewer crashes

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I have this custom code that i wrote awhile back in order to have a gradient border on my views.  Only problem is, it has slowly become my top crash in my app.

The crashlog I am getting in crashlytics points to the line `super.layoutSubviews()` which doesn't make much sense to me.

Anyone have any idea on improvements, or a different approach to doing this same thing, that can lead to fewer crashes? I get 120-200 a week from this view.

```
class GradientBorderView: UIView {
    var enableGradientBorder: Bool = false

    var borderGradientColors: [UIColor] = [] {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard enableGradientBorder && !borderGradientColors.isEmpty  else {
            layer.borderColor = nil
            return
        }
        let gradient = UIImage.imageGradient(bounds: bounds, colors: borderGradientColors)
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradient).cgColor
    }
}


extension UIImage {

    static func imageGradient(bounds: CGRect, colors: [UIColor]) -> UIImage {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map(\.cgColor)

        // This makes it left to right, default is top to bottom
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)

        return renderer.image { gradientLayer.render(in: $0.cgContext) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough to say why you would be getting crashes, unless you can provide code that reproduces it.

However, you may find using a `CAGradientLayer` with a `.mask` to be a better, more efficient option:

```
class MyGradientBorderView: UIView {
    
    var enableGradientBorder: Bool = false { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    var borderGradientColors: [UIColor] = [] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    var gradientBorderWidth: CGFloat = 8.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    let gLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let mskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard enableGradientBorder, gradientBorderWidth > 0.0, !borderGradientColors.isEmpty  else {
            gLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            return
        }
        if gLayer.superlayer == nil {
            layer.addSublayer(gLayer)
        }

        gLayer.frame = bounds
        gLayer.colors = borderGradientColors.map(\.cgColor)
        gLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        
        let w: CGFloat = gradientBorderWidth
        
        mskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds.insetBy(dx: w * 0.5, dy: w * 0.5)).cgPath
        mskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        mskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor  // any opaque color
        mskLayer.lineWidth = w
        gLayer.mask = mskLayer
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit** *-- addressing the need for rounded corners...*

There are a number of bugs with `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: ...`.

The biggest problems come into play when the `cornerRadius` is roughly 1/3rd of the short-side.

So, if the frame is `300 x 60` (perhaps to provide a border for a label), and we have a `cornerRadius` of `20`, things can get really ugly.

Instead of overwhelming with details, refer to these SO posts (among others):

- [How the iOS system draw the view corner shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829955/how-the-ios-system-draw-the-view-corner-shape)
- [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: the cornerRadius value is not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623415/uibezierpath-bezierpathwithroundedrect-the-cornerradius-value-is-not-consistent)
- [UIBezierPath issue with oval shape, lines sticks out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933879/uibezierpath-issue-with-oval-shape-lines-sticks-out)

Now, ***IF*** you will always have a clear background, and ***IF*** you will never approach the 1/3rd radius-to-side ratio, using `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: ...` with the above code should not be a problem.

However, here is another approach to your design goal that you *may* find more reliable and flexible...

We will keep the view background color clear, add a "fillLayer" for the desired background color, and we'll mask the gradient layer with a "plain" `CALayer` with it's border properties set.

```
class AnotherGradientBorderView: UIView {
    
    // override backgroundColor, because we want this view
    //  to always have a clear background
    // to avoid edge anti-aliasing artifacts
    //  we use the fillLayer as the background color
    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            super.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.bkgColor = newValue ?? .clear
        }
        get {
            return self.bkgColor
        }
    }
    
    public var enableGradientBorder: Bool = false { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var borderGradientColors: [UIColor] = [] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var gradientBorderWidth: CGFloat = 8.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    private var bkgColor: UIColor = .clear { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    private let gLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    private let fillLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(gLayer)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        fillLayer.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor

        let w: CGFloat = gradientBorderWidth
        let rad: CGFloat = cornerRadius

        self.layer.cornerRadius = rad

        let mskLayer = CALayer()
        mskLayer.frame = bounds
        mskLayer.cornerRadius = rad
        mskLayer.borderWidth = w
        mskLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor    // any opaque color
        gLayer.mask = mskLayer

        if enableGradientBorder, gradientBorderWidth > 0.0, !borderGradientColors.isEmpty {
            
            gLayer.opacity = 1.0
            
            gLayer.frame = bounds
            
            gLayer.colors = borderGradientColors.map(\.cgColor)
            gLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

            // to avoid edge anti-aliasing artifacts
            //  inset and adjust cornerRadius of fillLayer
            //  if gradient border is showing
            fillLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: w * 0.5, dy: w * 0.5)
            fillLayer.cornerRadius = rad - w * 0.5

        } else {

            gLayer.opacity = 0.0

            fillLayer.frame = bounds
            fillLayer.cornerRadius = rad
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**Example controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var gbViews: [AnotherGradientBorderView] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        for _ in 1...4 {
            
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.textAlignment = .center
            lbl.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
            lbl.text = "Label behind/underneath the gradient border view."
            lbl.numberOfLines = 0
            lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(lbl)

            let v = AnotherGradientBorderView()
            v.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.20)
            v.borderGradientColors = [.red, .yellow]
            v.enableGradientBorder = true
            v.cornerRadius = 20.0
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
                
                lbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerXAnchor),
                lbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerYAnchor),
                lbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            ])
            
            gbViews.append(v)
        }
        
        gbViews[2].cornerRadius = 0.0
        gbViews[3].cornerRadius = 0.0
        
        gbViews[1].backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        gbViews[3].backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            gbViews[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            gbViews[1].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gbViews[0].bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            gbViews[2].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gbViews[1].bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            gbViews[3].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gbViews[2].bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        gbViews.forEach { v in
            v.enableGradientBorder.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Output - note that on the first and third instances, I used `.black.withAlphaComponent(0.20)` for the background color instead of `.clear` -- otherwise when we toggle off the gradient border we wouldn't see anything:

[image]

tapping anywhere toggles the gradient border:

[image]

Comment: is there resources to read up on to explain why this is better / more efficient?

Comment: @daredevil1234 - not sure where to point you for resources... as a rule, though, Layers (plain, shape, gradient, etc) are very highly optimized. Rendering a `UIImage` every time `layoutSubviews()` is called will be less efficient. Keep in mind that you're rendering to the screen scale. So, if I have my view filling the safe-area on an iPhone 15 Pro, the view size `393 x 759` which renders a `1179 × 2277 pixel` gradient `UIImage`.

Comment: i accepted the answer.  Could you do me a favor and make a small edit though? I used `mskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: w * 0.5, dy: w * 0.5), byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.layer.cornerRadius, height: self.layer.cornerRadius)).cgPath` instead in order to correctly have rounded corners with this, otherwise, the corners will look weird.  This way, it is corrected for people in the future who see the post

Comment: I'll be releasing this change Jan 3rd and will update Jan 10th to see if it has had an effect and didn't introduce new crashes (doubt)

Comment: @daredevil1234 - you're referencing `self.layer.cornerRadius` ... is your `GradientBorderView` going to always have a `.clear` background color? If so, you're all set with using `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: ...`. However, if it may have a non-clear background color, we'll need to make a few changes.

Comment: @daredevil1234 - also worth noting... that was intended to be **Example Code** only. Also, you had not mentioned rounded-corners in your original post. `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: ...` has a number of known bugs. ***If you've fully tested your implementation,*** and everything looks as you expect, great. If you see any problems, though, I can provide you alternative code to avoid the bugs.

Comment: visually everything looks good, and we are a small team so only did some run through tests.  what are the known bugs with `UIBezierPath(roundedRect`?  we didn't seem to notice any issue, but if you have an alternative suggestion, I would love to give it a try.  and correct, my post lacked details on that it used maskedCorners / cornerRadius / masksToBounds. thanks so much!

Comment: @daredevil1234 - see the (long) **Edit** to my answer.